# Sets that are isomorphic as rings but have different topological properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

I have recently been studying some introductory field theory, and I came across the theorem stating that if $p(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible, then there is a field containing a copy of $F$ in which $p(x)$ has a root.  The construction of this extension field $K/F$ went something like this

\begin{equation*}
K = F[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle
\end{equation*}

It is easy to see that there is an isomorphism $\phi: F \to \phi(F) \subset K$.  But in a strict set-theoretic sense, $F$ is not a subset of $K$.  Yet it seems that algebraists are eager to treat $F$ as literally being contained in $K$ because of this isomorphism.

But the isomorphism only assures that the algebraic properties of $F$ and $\phi(F)$ are the same.  In other words, their "Multiplication tables" or "Cayley tables" (or whatever you want to call the tables that define their binary operations) are the same, except that different symbols are used.

And since algebraists (presumably) only care about the algebraic properties, this seems like it would be OK in an algebra context.  But what if $\phi(F)$ has different topological properties than $F$, even though $F \cong \phi(F)$?  [From the above example at least, this seems plausible to me because the field $\phi(F)$ looks nothing like $F$.]

So my question is: Is there an example of two rings $R$ and $S$ where $R \cong S$ but $R$ has different topological properties than $S$?

Comment: Absolutely: one can put a number of topologies on any given ring, although perhaps this is uninteresting unless the topologies are compatible with addition and multiplication. As an example, $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb C_p$ (the completion of the algebraic closure of [$\Bbb Q_p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number)) are abstractly isomorphic as rings, but not isomorphic as topological rings (e.g., $\Bbb C_p$ is not locally compact). The topologies on $\Bbb C_p$ and $\Bbb C$ make both topological fields in natural ways, yet are still different topologically while isomorphic algebraically.

Comment: Typically, when one has a natural topology on a structure, one will take this into account when considering maps between similar objects (otherwise, you're forgetting a lot of information you care about!). For example, the absolute Galois group $G_K$ of a field $K$ can be equipped with the profinite topology, and then one will generally require maps from or to $G_K$ to be continuous with respect to this topology. So, if you have two topological rings $R$ and $S$, you'll say they're isomorphic if you have a *continuous* ring isomorphism $R\to S$ with continuous inverse.

Comment: @Stahl  Great example.  What do you mean by "...unless the topologies are  compatible with addition and multiplication"?

Comment: I mean that $+ : R\times R\to R$ and $\cdot : R\times R\to R$ are continuous, where $R$ has the given topology and $R\times R$ has the product topology; i.e., $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a [topological ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ring) if $R$ is a topological space and $+ : R\times R\to R$, $- : R\times R\to R$ and $\cdot : R\times R\to R$ are continuous maps of topological spaces such that the usual ring axioms for these maps are satisfied.

Comment: @Stahl  Thanks.  This is helpful.  I like the idea of just using the same space $R$ and putting two different topologies on it.

Comment: Perhaps you should think about your motivation for this question a little bit. What topology do you propose for $K=F[x]/(p)$? Can you come up with one  for which $F$ and $\phi(F)$ are not homeomorphic?